# IOS Bug, keyboard not showing up

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

We encontered a problem in IOS, we have tested many webview packages from https://pub.dev/ (like    https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter and  [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin](http://%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappbrowser) and all the solutions ends with the same result.
When the innapp website opens, it loads perfectly, but when you interact with an input, the keyboard doesn't seems show up, it occurs in all the inputs from all the pages.

Thanks in advance!.

The error log output is:

```
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
   "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6040004826c0 h=-&- v=-&- UIToolbar:0x7fcec747c950.width == _UIInputViewContent:0x7fcec74aede0.width   (active)>", 
   "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000487440 h=--& v=--& _UIInputViewContent:0x7fcec74aede0.width == 0   (active)>", 
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004839d0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcec74bfd40]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcec743d460 )>", 
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000483a70 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x7fcec74bfd40.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcec743d460.trailing + 8   (active)>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004845b0 _UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcec743d460.trailing == UIToolbar:0x7fcec747c950.trailing   (active)>",  
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009f1d0 H:|-(0)-[_UIToolbarContentView:0x7fcec743d460]   (active, names: '|':UIToolbar:0x7fcec747c950 )>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000480730 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcec75b34b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcec75b2e40 )>",   
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000480780 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcec75b34b0]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcec75b2e40 )>", 
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000481310 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcec75b4060'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcec75b39d0 )>", 
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000481360 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fcec75b4060'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fcec75b39d0 )>",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle between the "software keyboard" and "hardware keyboard" with using the shortcut is `⇧+⌘+K` or `⌘+K`

Comment: Thanks so much!, we didn't notice that feature on the simulator.